# C# Processstartinfo. Proceso de Excel con argumentos para formato: Unicode (UTF-8)

Tags: c#, excel, utf-8, proceso

Quisiera saber qué debo pasar como argumentos, a un proceso de Excel, para que un archivo de texto (.txt) Excel lo abra con “Origen del archivo” en “65001 : Unicode (UTF-8)”. Me explico mejor, tengo el siguiente código:

```
internal class Excel
{
    public void AbrirEnExcel(string trayectoriaExcel, string archivo)
    {
        if (archivo != "" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(trayectoriaExcel) && File.Exists(trayectoriaExcel + "\\" + "EXCEL.EXE"))
        {
            ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = trayectoriaExcel + "\\" + "EXCEL.EXE" };
            ps.ErrorDialog = false;

            ps.Arguments = "\"" + archivo + "\"";
            ps.CreateNoWindow = true;
            ps.UseShellExecute = false;
            ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            using (Process proc = new Process())
            {
                proc.StartInfo = ps;
                proc.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Al llamar al método “AbrirEnExcel” le paso un fichero de texto que tiene caracteres con tildes y caracteres ‘ñ’, está en formato “Unicode (UTF-8)”, pero no lo respeta lo abre en formato “Windows (ANSI)”.

El fichero de texto tiene estas líneas:

Andalucía

España

Galicia

País Vasco

Murcia

y Excel genera la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se abre un archivo .txt en Excel, y me refiero de forma normal, no programando, Excel te da la opción de especificar el “Origen del fichero”. Si se abre en modo “Windows (ANSI)” no respeta los caracteres latinos, si se abre en modo “65001 : Unicode (UTF-8)”, si se respetan los caracteres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Sabe alguien si se puede poner en el Processstartinfo algún argumento para que Excel abra el fichero en Unicode (UTF-8)?. Gracias. Espero haberme explicado bien.